# Reported errors limit: gcflags -e seems to be ignored

Tags: go, compiler-errors

In Go, how do I change the number of reported compilation errors? `-gcflags="-e"` seems to be ignored.

Even if I build with these flags, I get:

```
$ go build -gcflags=-e ...
....
filename.go:528:44: too many errors
```

How can I see all errors?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with 1.17.5. Which version are you using? Consider also that using the wildcard `...` instead of `./...` will attempt to build all packages in the std lib.

Comment: @blackgreen: I use 1.15 at the moment, but I have `-e` in `go tool compile -help`, and so I expect it should be supported